# Reset other program's RAM to previous state

Tags: memory, save, load, ram, savestate

So I know that programs like Cheat Engine can alter variables in RAM other programs are using.

Is there any way to save all the RAM a program is using at one point in time, and then load that back into a program? 
So suppose I hit a button, my program would reset the other program to its last "save state"

How would one go about implementing this, and what would be the best way to do so?

If this is possible in something like Java, C#, or Python, that'd be best, since I'm most familiar in those, but if it's not, I'm happy to start looking into something.

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably looking for something like [ReadProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx) and its companion Write function. Look for examples, though, there's bound to be some lying around that you can use - in C# at least.

Comment: @500-internal-server-error that seems very helpful! However, it seems to require a length, but I want to retrieve all the information.  Is there a good way to get the length of the full app for me to pass?

Comment: Actually, I think this may have the info I need: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716227/Csharp-How-to-Scan-a-Process-Memory. I'll check it out more tomorrow.  Thanks for the help!